# Number of ways to stand in queue for the 2 families with a given constraint

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Two different families of 3 persons each - father, mother and child - are standing in a queue to get into the football stadium.  In how many ways can they enter the stadium such that for each person the following is true: the wife is ahead of the husband, the child is behind the father ?

**Approach:-**

I can't think of an approach involving Permutations and Combinations, but rather started listing cases one by one like first of all took the families as Family 1 and Family 2 and the people in them as F1, M1, C1 and F2, M2, C2

M1 F1 C1 M2 F2 C2

M1 F1 M2 C1 F2 C2

M1 M2 F1 C1 F2 C2

M2 M1 F1 C1 F2 C2
.... It is taking a lot of time to list like these and top of that I feel like there is a high chance of missing some cases by writing like this, can someone help me out with more efficient way using PnC

Comment: When you write "for each person the following is true" did you mean to write "for each *family* the following is true" ?

Comment: Assuming that you did, then note that all you need to do is to specify which of the three slots (out of a total of six) family $\#1$ occupies.

Comment: I have no idea what that means.  What you wrote does not make sense...if you agree with my guess as to your meaning, edit your post accordingly.  If you meant something else, please edit for clarity.

Comment: I have this much question only given to me, the answer is given as simply 6c3 =20, I can't figure out what they did

Comment: Which is what I said in an earlier comment, right?

Comment: @Fin27 i think the question should have used "for each family" instead of "for each person" , but the question is still understandable , so think like that we have $6$ gaps in a line , select $3$ of them by $C(6,3)$ to place one of the families , it can be done only one way because of the restriction.After that we will have only one way to place the remaining family , so $C(6,3) \times 1 =20$

Comment: Thank you @Bulbasaur !